# Connecting ASP.NET with Access database 2010 using windows 7 x64

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I'm trying to use a database I have in Access 2010 and trying to connect it using ASP.NET. Currently, I'm using Visual Studio 2010, Windows 7 x64, Office 2010 x86 (but I already tried with Office 2010 x64) and using **OleDb**. I was told that it isn't that easy if you have a x64 system because of the data provider.

I already tried a lot of connection strings for this code snippet:

```
Protected Sub btnRegister_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegister.Click
    Dim DBPath As String = "C:\Users\Rodrigo\Documents\Database1.accdb"
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DBPath & ";Persist Security Info=False;")
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    With cmd
        .CommandText = "insert into Users (nome) values (" & Me.txtNome.Text & ")"
        .Connection = cn
        .Connection.Open()
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
        .Connection.Close()
        .Dispose()
    End With
    cn.Dispose()
End Sub
```

The farthest I could get was with the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider which generated an error on `.ExecuteNonQuery()`, saying that it needs some arguments.

What would be the correct way to insert data in my access database using ASP.NET given my settings?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: I don't care for now, as long as my code runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use SQL parameters.

You're inserting an unquoted string into your SQL, resulting in invalid SQL.

Comment: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/26/Parameter-Queries-in-ASP.NET-with-MS-Access